# Conversion fails (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a column

**StudentData** (`varchar`)

Sample values:

```
Not regular
90
15.2
55
4
0
>15
regular
35
```

I have a condition to find out all the students which have `StudentData` value greater than 10
or have a NULL value.

When I try to convert it fails saying conversion fails. How can get those values? I am expecting a resultset something like

```
studentdata
90
15.2
55

35
```

Please advice.

Comment: You want to look at using the ISNUMERIC function

Comment: how can i handle the NULL values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
select * from t
where studentdata is null or 
  (isnumeric(studentdata) = 1 and CAST(studentdata AS float) > 10)
```

Anyway, you should consider storing appropriate information in that column, instead of a mix of things.

Let me know if you have any issue with it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [isnumeric()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) but it has some issues. [IsNumeric() Broken? Only up to a point.](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/philfactor/archive/2011/01/13/98746.aspx)

Something like should work for you.

```
select *
from YourTable
where
  case when isnumeric(studentdata+'E0') = 1
    then cast(studentdata as float)
    else 0
  end > 10
```